# C# How does this Bitmap get updated when Graphics.DrawImage is called?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics

The following code works fine, but I do not understand how `newBitmap` gets changed:

```
Image img = Image.FromStream(
    new MemoryStream(imgBytes)
);

// New X/Y reduce by 10%
x = ((img.Width / 10) * 9);
y = ((img.Height / 10) * 9);

Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(x,y);                         

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap);                 

g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, x, y);                           
g.Dispose();

Image newImg = (Image)newBitmap;
```

1. `newBitmap` is created as an empty bitmap in the new dimensions, and is not touched again.
2. A `Graphics g` object is created from the empty `newBitmap`.
3. The `g.DrawImage` draws the **original** image.

Nothing has touched `newBitmap`.  But when I cast `newBitmap` to `newImg` at the end, `newBitmap` is indeed a resized copy of my original `img`.  But I didn't do anything to it.

How does this happen?

Comment: `The g.DrawImage draws the original image` into bitmap it was created from (ie newBitmap variable)

Comment: @IłyaBursov, so you mean that there is a link between the graphic and the bitmap it was created from?  That would explain it.  If you will add that as an answer, I will mark it accepted.  Thanks.

Comment: yes, there is link between these two objects